# reading from 1 pipe multiple writers

Tags: c, pipe, fork, read-write, xv6

We are trying to read char* data from a pipe given to multiple child processes .

 each child writes a char* into a shared pipe, which the parent process reads from. 

 what we're trying to do is parse the information on a children processes running in xv6. 

 when parsing a single process, we don't have any trouble, but when parsing a pipe process, which has a recursive call to "runcmd" the following problem accures: 

 we used the following code in the parent's end:

```
while(read(p[0],buff,sizeof(buff)) > 0){
  printf(1,"\nprocess from pipe in main: " );
  printf(1,buff);
  printf(1,"\n");
}
```

and in the children end:

```
char * name = ecmd->argv[0];
char * data=(char*)malloc(strlen(name)*sizeof(char)+strlen(pidc2)*sizeof(char)+3);
strcpy(data,name);
char* delimiter="#";
strcpy(data+strlen(name),delimiter);
strcpy(data+strlen(name)+strlen(delimiter),pidc2);
strcpy(data+strlen(name)+strlen(delimiter)+strlen(pidc2),"\0");
write(pp[1],data,sizeof(char)*(strlen(data)));
```

when we run this code with "ls|cat", it will print:

```
ls#*some_pid*cat#*some_pid*
```

instead of reading from each child and printing

```
ls#*some_pid*
cat#*some_pid*
```

why won't it send them separately?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Your child code shows no pipe code - very confusing. What is the big picture? Wnat do you want to achieve?

Comment: What happens if you replace `"\0"` with `"\n"`?

Answer (score 0):

Because that is just how pipes work. Internally, the operating system is combining the data from all the writers into a single stream. As comments above suggest, you can have each writer insert some kind of record separator ('\0' or '\n'), then have the reading process look for and split the record at the separators.

I don't know about xv6 specifically, but traditionally unix-like systems have guaranteed (and in fact this is a posix.1 requirement) that a write of any message below a certain specified length will be atomic (i.e. if two processes both write 'foo ', the reader will see 'foo foo ' not 'ffooo o ' or any other permutation).